# HP/Agilent 34401A low beep sound level

Tags: multimeter, sound

I want to modify the internal beep sound pressure level of this bench DMM and make it louder.

I have a problem with my ears and I won't be able to hear the the beep sound well when making continuity measurements. The beeper is small (well, not so small, is a Murata piezo speaker.) Looking at the schematic, the Murata is continuously receiving 5VDC, and when you use the continuity mode shorting the probes, the circuit sends around 2.4VDC, with a mixed square wave to make the beeper/speaker beep noise.

I was thinking of using a kind of simple design using an opamp (the 34401A has a 12VDC rail inside,) or maybe with a couple of transistors will be better.

Maybe I'm getting deaf, but the only DMM I can hear is the Fluke 87, which uses a differend kind of beeping sound, bi-frequency, not a "piiiiiii" one (which, if you vary your head's position with respect to the DMM you won't be able to hear it well)

PD: Here is the part of the schematic which shows the piezo speaker:

[image]

Comment: It would be better to share the relevant section of the schematic and the transducer part number (or preferably datasheet) from the BOM if you have it.

Comment: Alright. I will do it ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: Respecting the piezo speaker (E700 in the schematic), the manufacturer's reference is 9164-0173. In the HP parts list indicate "Alarm-audible 25V".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this, only 5 jellybean parts:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDb0y7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If it's too loud, add a resistor in series with C1. This gives about 21Vp-p rather than about 5Vp-p across the piezo.

It will function (at least for a time) without C1/R4 but C1 and R4 maintain ~0Vdc across the piezo when not active, which is recommended by manufacturers to prevent silver migration in the element, and subsequent failures.

Comment: Wow!, thanks a lot! It looks very nice. I will keep you informed. I will try it out in my breadboard andI hope this will definitely make a loder beep!. I'm anxious to try it out!

Comment: I finally done it!. And it worked. Done some mods, but much higher volume. Thanks a lot for your schematic. You make my day. I have a couple of DDMs with an extremely poor beepers (I think they are Rigols). I don’t have the schematic, but I hope it won’t be so complicated. [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q2KD.jpg)

Comment: Thanks @SamGibson. I don't know how to post an answer including a pic without adding as a comment.

Comment: @Fichamba - Hi, I think you said that exactly the wrong way round, didn't you? I think you meant that you didn't know how to post a *comment* which included a pic, without writing an *answer* (yes, it isn't obvious how to do it). || Since it wasn't really an *answer*, I converted it into that comment above. || If you want to include an image (e.g. schematic) in a comment, use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. Ask on [Meta] if that's unclear. Thanks

Comment: Again, thank you for the explanation!.